# Как в Реакт можно реалиозовать отправку изображений в сообщениях

Tags: firebase, chat, reactjs

Я сделал чат с помощью firebase, но мне нужно как-то понимать отправляю я обычный текст, ссылку, или ссылку на изображения. Как это можно сделать? В какую сторону копать? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно создать объект Image, в котором вызвать метод onload, который позволяет определить является ли текст ссылкой на картинку.

```js
function loadImage(src) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.addEventListener("load", () => resolve(img));
      img.src = src;
  });
};
loadImage("https://www.tokkoro.com/picsup/5550850-landscape-wallpapers.jpg")//картинка
 .then(()=>{console.log('сработает')})
loadImage("https://www.tokkoro.com/picsup")//не картинка
.then(()=>{console.log('не сработает')}) //в then отлавливаем успешное событие.В моем случае,в коллбэке я вызываю рендер картинки
```